# ToC and memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices

I am using a `memoir` class with this thesis template: [Caltech thesis template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/caltech-thesis-latex-template-with-logo/kgwqvkbfkwmx#.WdVy8tN94zY)

When I used `\begin{appendices} text \end{appendices}`, in the main text, the chapter name is `Appendix A` but in the ToC it shows `Chapter A`.

For example,

```
\chapter{text1}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{text2}
\end{appendices}
\chapter{text3}
```

In the main text, I get

```
Chapter 1 text1
Appendix A text2
Chapter 2 text3
```

In the ToC, I get

```
Chapter 1 text1
Chapter A text2
Chapter 2 text3
```

What should I do to fix that?

I want to use the `appendices` environment because I want to have the appendix to show up in between regular chapters.

I can modify `\appendix` to make it work by

```
\apptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\chaptername}{Appendix}
  }%
}{}{}
```

But, if I place `\appendix` in the main text, the rest of the chapters becomes appendix, and I only want some subset of chapters after `\appendix` to have the `Appendix` label.

Note: The `appendix` package with `titletoc` option does not work with `memoir` class.

Comment: How do you add `Chapter` to your ToC? [Here is a minimal example](https://pastebin.com/ft3kH4Ca) that you can use to start showing us what you're doing.

Comment: Here is how
    \chapter{text1}
    \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{text2}
    \end{appendices}
    \chapter{text3}

So, the final result should have Chapter 1 text1, Appendix A text2, Chapter 2 text3 in the TOC. Instead, it has Chapter 1 text1, Chapter A text2, Chapter 2 text3 in the TOC.

Comment: (1) please make a full minimal example, (2) as far as I remember memoir does not prefix anything in the toc by default, so you are not giving all information. (3) `\cftchapternane` and `\cftappendixname` are the normal go to macros in memoir for this.

Comment: I added the template I used. That's all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following patches should correct your ToC display, using `Appendix` within the `appendices` environment and `Chapter` elsewhere:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\anappendixtrue}}
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\anappendixfalse}}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
  \ifanappendix
    Appendix% or \appendixname
  \else
    Chapter% or \chaptername
  \fi
  \space\formatchapternumber{#1}:\space}
```

Add the above code somewhere in your preamble.

Comment: This works great! Thank you for the quick responses.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, I do not understand the problem. The normal `memoir` methods works fine:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{text1}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{text2}
\end{appendices}
\chapter{text3}
\end{document}
```

Whether that template is doing stuff that is should not is out of my hands.